# Orbeon: How to display form warnings in generated PDF

Tags: pdf, orbeon

When I press save or review in the Orbeon form runner, warnings are displayed for all incorrect values.

When I emulate the print media using Chrome dev tools (`F12 -> ... -> More tools -> Rendering -> Emulate CSS media -> print`), these warnings are still visible.

However, when I create a PDF using the `PDF` button, the warnings are removed. Is there a way around this? I would like to see all warnings in the generated PDF.

I thought about using a custom print CSS like this:

```
@media print {
   .xforms-alert{
       display: block !important;
   }
}
```

But this does not do anything...

Demo form [here](http://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/test-warnings-in-pdf/test-warnings-in-pdf/edit/4cad3137d972dd8ac0576579fca33ead776a8589).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that currently, there is no way to show the warnings in the PDF, or even in Review mode: the HTML markup does not include alerts at all in these cases, whether for errors or for warnings.

Comment: So there is absolutely no way I can do this :(?
Is there a possibility to extract the error & warnings some other way?
The problem is that I don't want to enforce certain validation rules (use warnings instead of errors) but I still would like to get some kind of overview of the "quality" of the form when it was submitted.

Comment: That's right, there is no way to get this into the PDF (besides making a change to the product). For error and warnings, you can `send` the document to a service and [enable annotations](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes/actions-form-runner-send.html#annotating-xml-data).